# Android animations (zoom+fade out): weird bug

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I want to make a repetitive animation where I scale up and fade out an ImageView (both animations at the same time).

Here is my code:

```
    <com.xxxx.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/redImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/red_square"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
  
        />




float scaleMax = 1f;
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setStartOffset(0);
fadeOut.setDuration(1500);

Animation scale1 = new ScaleAnimation(0, scaleMax, 0, scaleMax, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
scale1.setDuration(1500);
scale1.setStartOffset(0);


animSet.setFillEnabled(true);

animSet.addAnimation(scale1);
animSet.addAnimation(fadeOut);

animSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        view.startAnimation(animSet);


    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


    }
});


view.startAnimation(animSet);
```

The image scales up and fades out correctly. Nevertheless, it appears shortly (0.1s) at full scale and without transparency between two animations. I don't understand why.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: So, when restarting your animation it does show up without transparency? Or does it not play the two animations at the same time and shows the image full-size between the two animations?

Comment: probably because you are starting AnimationSets over and over, try animSet.cancel() before you start it again in onAnimationEnd()

Comment: @AHoneyBustard That is it! I can't belive that I have to call cancel() in onAnimationEnd...  Android is so badly coded... Crazy. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem, I wouldnt say Android is badly coded, although I agree that AnimationSets are buggy and I would advise anyone to use ViewPropertyAnimator instead. Anyways for future visitors I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting the AnimationSet over and over, so for fluency you need to

```
animSet.cancel();
```

every animation you started, before you start it over in onAnimationEnd().